# How to get objects from data base with fields marked LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have some problem with method findAll() in DAO layer. Finally it gets all object correctly, but have some error with "null" in process.

For example, class Group has field Faculty, Faculty is POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements ModelEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "groups_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groups_seq", sequenceName = "groups_group_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id")
    private Faculty faculty;
```

here is findAll() in dao:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        logger.debug("findAll()");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = (CriteriaQuery<T>) criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getEntityClass());
        Root<T> rootEntry = (Root<T>) criteriaQuery.from(getEntityClass());
        CriteriaQuery<T> all = criteriaQuery.select(rootEntry);
        TypedQuery<T> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);
        List<T> result = allQuery.getResultList();
        logger.trace("findAll() found {} entries.", result.size());
        return result;
    }
```

When I go on site to /groups/getAll browser displays all groups and faculties in their columns, all OK, but in console I see `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` which start from `List<T> result = allQuery.getResultList();`
when I choose FetchType.EAGER the same situation- all records here, but NPE in console.
How to beat NPE in console?

logs look like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.lambda$visitQuerySpec$18(SqlTreePrinter.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logNode(SqlTreePrinter.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logNode(SqlTreePrinter.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.visitQuerySpec(SqlTreePrinter.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.lambda$visitStatement$0(SqlTreePrinter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logNode(SqlTreePrinter.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logNode(SqlTreePrinter.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.visitStatement(SqlTreePrinter.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.print(SqlTreePrinter.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.StandardSqlAstSelectTranslator.translate(StandardSqlAstSelectTranslator.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.resolveCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1356)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:136)
    at com.rumakin.universityschedule.dao.Dao.findAll(Dao.java:71)
    at com.rumakin.universityschedule.service.AuditoriumService.findAll(AuditoriumService.java:35)
    at com.rumakin.universityschedule.controllers.AuditoriumController.findAll(AuditoriumController.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
03:21:08.012 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.tree -
                SQL AST Tree:
    -> [select-statement]
      -> [query-spec]
        -> [select]
          selection - org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.SqlSelectionImpl@d1311e6a
          selection - org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.SqlSelectionImpl@429797b9
          selection - org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.SqlSelectionImpl@78d44e89
          selection - org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.SqlSelectionImpl@ea2bc8b8
        <- [select]
        -> [from]
          -> [table-group]
            -> [Auditorium as a1_0]
          <- [table-group]
        <- [from]
      <- [query-spec]
    <- [select-statement]
```

Comment: Looks like this NPE happens in the hibernate SQL logging code. Turn off the SQL AST logging

Comment: but why does it happed? It looks like in any casy(LAZY or EAGER) works LAZY

Comment: From the stacktrace I can see you are using Hibernate 6 which is still in an alpha state. I would recommend you use Hibernate 5.4 if you want something working right now